# Manipulate a Nested Dictionary/List Tree in Python 3

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator

I'm trying to work with pandoc's JSON AST format.

It formats it out like this.

```
[
  {
    "unMeta": {
      "date": {
        "t": "MetaInlines", "c": [
          {"t": "Str", "c": "2015-08-23"}]},
      "version": {
        "t": "MetaString",  "c": "0.22"},
      "author": {
        "t": "MetaInlines", "c": [
          {"t": "Str", "c": "John"},
          {"t": "Space", "c": []},
          {"t": "Str", "c": "MacFarlane"}]},
      "title": {
        "t": "MetaInlines", "c": [
          {"t": "Str", "c": "CommonMark"},
          {"t": "Space", "c": []},
          {"t": "Str", "c": "Spec"}]},
      "license": {
        "t": "MetaInlines", "c": [
          {"t": "Link", "c": [
            [
              {"t": "Str", "c": "CC-BY-SA"},
              {"t": "Space", "c": []},
              {"t": "Str", "c": "4.0"}
            ],
            ["http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/", ""]]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  [
    {"t": "Header", "c": [1, ["introduction", [], []], [
      {"t": "Str", "c": "Introduction"}]]},
    {"t": "Header", "c": [2, ["what-is-markdown", [], []], [
      {"t": "Str", "c": "What"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "is"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "Markdown?"}]]},
    {"t": "Para", "c": [
      {"t": "Str", "c": "Markdown"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "is"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "a"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "plain"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "text"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "format"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "for"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "writing"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "structured"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "documents,"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "based"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "on"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "conventions"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "used"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "for"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "indicating"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "formatting"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "in"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "email"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "and"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "usenet"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "posts."},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "It"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "was"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "developed"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "in"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "2004"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "by"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "John"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "Gruber,"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "who"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "wrote"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "the"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "first"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "Markdown-to-HTML"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "converter"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "in"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "perl,"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "and"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "it"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "soon"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "became"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "widely"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "used"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "in"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "websites."},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "By"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "2014"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "there"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "were"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "dozens"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "of"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "implementations"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "in"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "many"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "languages."},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "Some"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "of"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "them"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "extended"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "basic"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "Markdown"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "syntax"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "with"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "conventions"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "for"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "footnotes,"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "definition"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "lists,"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "tables,"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "and"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "other"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "constructs,"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "and"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "some"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "allowed"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "output"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "not"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "just"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "in"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "HTML"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "but"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "in"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "LaTeX"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "and"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "many"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "other"},
      {"t": "Space", "c": []},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "formats."}]}]]
```

How can I mutate/reformat this so that when `"t"` and `"c"` are the dictionary keys, I get a more readable dictionary where the value of the dictionary key `t` is the key of my new dictionary, and the value of `'c'` is the value of my new dictionary.

The successful results would look something like this:

```
{
    "unMeta": {
      "date": {
        "MetaInlines": [
          {"Str": "2015-08-23"}]},
      "version": {
        "MetaString": "0.22"},
      "author": {
        "MetaInlines": [
          {"Str": "John"},
          {"Space": []},
          {"Str": "MacFarlane"}]},
      "title": {
        "MetaInlines": [
          {"Str": "CommonMark"},
          {"Space": []},
          {"Str": "Spec"}]},
      "license": {
        "MetaInlines": [
          {"Link": [
            [
              {"Str": "CC-BY-SA"},
              {"Space": []},
              {"Str": "4.0"}
            ],
            ["http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/", ""]]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

My current strategy is this. Inside a while loop I'm iterating until `"t"` and `"c"` are found as the keys of a dictionary, then I'm calling a function on the dictionary containing the keys, which returns a new dictionary, setting `found` to `True` and over righting the original dictionary value, then letting the while loop run until it finds no more instances. Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you  share the code you've written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is your loop going to check all of the dictionaries within the main list, all of the dictionaries within those dictionaries, and the lists of dictionaries inside each inner dictionary, etc...? This type of problem is often solved with recursion. This function goes through the values in the original list. When it comes across a `{'t':x, 'c':y}` dictionary it alters it to `{x: y}` in place. When it comes across any other kind of dictionary or list the function calls itself on the item.

```
def mutate(iterable):
    if isinstance(iterable, list):
        indexed_list = enumerate(iterable)
    elif isinstance(iterable, dict):
        indexed_list = iterable.items()
    for k, item in indexed_list:
        if isinstance(item, dict) and sorted(item.keys()) == ['c', 't']:
            iterable[k] = {item['t']: item['c']}
        if isinstance(item, dict) or isinstance(item, list):
            mutate(item)
```